How can I convert XYZ Euler to ZXY without changing the camera movement?
I’m trying to change the rotation order without disrupting the current camera movement. Is there a way to do this? If so, could I get an explanation?
When I change the Euler rotation order in the Transform settings, the change doesn’t seem to export in the FBX file. Could there be additional steps needed during export to apply the new rotation values? (I am selecting 'Apply Transform' in the export settings.)
Thanks to anyone who replies!
